# how can i add value on bar in the charts in chart.js vs 3.x

Tags: chart.js

[image]

expected result

I am trying to the value of the chart on top of every bar. I tried one of the example
[Adding custom text to Bar Chart label values using Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760698/adding-custom-text-to-bar-chart-label-values-using-chart-js).
But it didnt work.
Also added the script in html page

```
<div>
         canvas id="myChart1_1"></canvas>
 </div>
         
  <script src="static/graphs.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>"
```

graph.js contains the code.

```
const labels1_1 = ['1','2','3', '4', '5','6','7', '8','9+'];
const data1_1 = {
  labels: labels1_1,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Trucks',
    data: [1,2,3, 4, 5,6,7, 8,9],
    backgroundColor: '#4472C4',
    borderColor: '#4472C4',
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
};  
const config1_1 = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data1_1,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Number of SS vs Number of Trucks'
            },
            datalabels: {
              align: 'end',
              anchor: 'end',
              backgroundColor: '#3472C4' 
              },               
        },
    
      scales: {
               
        y: {
            display:true,
          beginAtZero: true,
          title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'SS'
          }
          
        },
                
      }
    },
  };

const myChart1_1 = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart1_1'), config1_1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datalabels is since V2 (of datalabels) and V3 (of Chart.js) not self registerable anymore.

So at the top of your `graph.js` file you will need to register the datalabels plugin like so:

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
```